# Is there an alternative to SQL view where the query is executed before reading from it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-view

As I've understood it, in an SQL view, you pay for the query time upon querying the view. My particular problem is I have a bound of a maximum 30 sec query time when I fetch my data (SQL view) from an API endpoint. Is there a better alternative for the case where you want to join data together before sending it through the API? Data gets updated frequently.

My SQL View

```
CREATE VIEW sql_view AS
SELECT 
     A.some_data1
    ,B.some_data2
    ,C.some_data3
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN C ON A.id_session = C.id_session
WHERE
    C.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
        A.id_session = (
        SELECT MAX(id_session)
        FROM A AS AA
        WHERE AA.id = A.id
    );
```

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "materialized view", and, as far as I know, MySQL doesn't support them.

Comment: If this query is slow then you need to look at the EXPLAIN PLAN for the query and work out if there is a better indexing strategy you could implement

Comment: Thanks @RobbyCornelissen. I think I will end up with the solution: 1: create 'snapshot' table, 2: create procedure for truncating and recreating that table, 3: event scheduler to automatically call the procedure.